# Notes and Attachments on Communities VF Page

Tags: visualforce-component, attachment, customer-community

We have a VF Page that we are exposing to community users and on that page, we want to display the RL for Notes and Attachments. We have the following snippet

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!Contact}" list="CombinedAttachments" />
```

However, when we add this line to our VF Page and access as a community user we get a VF error on like below[image]

We have tried several things already, such as check security settings, ensure the notes and attachments is on the page layout, check the API version to 28/29, use NotesAndAttachments instead of CombinedAttachments.

So I wanted to confirm if it is possible to display the Notes and Attachments related list on a VF page that is being accessed via communities ? or wether we need to build something custom (hopefully not)

Comment: whats the error when you included NotesAndAttachments and whats the behaviour of page when run in Admin mode?

Comment: The error is what you can see in the screenshot above, in admin mode it works fine. But I have checked the security settings ? so not sure if there is anything specific I should be looking for in the security settings

Comment: I guess viewing contacts is not allowed for community customer..as a commuity user try and search for that conract...I am sure you wont be able to view using standard SFDC UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be the answer to my question.

Notes and Attachments are not available on Accounts/Contacts for Customer Portal users. See the idea below,

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrTdAAK